# Desktop Google/Twitter/Facebook Accounts Authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth, openid, desktop

I've recently started working on a game project for mobiles for which I want to maintain user accounts.

Instead of writing my own user accounts layer, I thought I'd allow people to authenticate with Google/Facebook/Twitter etc. accounts. Examining the delegated authentication schemes supported by each of these providers like OAuth/OpenID, it seems like there must be a browser for logging in any of the providers. Can anyone suggest workarounds or straightforward ways to authenticate without having to open a browser.

If that's not possible, how are applications like Google Talk logging in without opening a browser?

Answer (score 0):

The browser is simply speaking HTTP (over TCP).  You can create an ASP.NET web service or a WCF web service which also speaks HTTP, which will follow the same sequence of HTTP actions.

Comment: OAuth v1 (e.g. Twitter) allows a customer to "allow" your application and store predefined a token/secret pair. Your application can use this to authenticate.